# In Bash, Kill background function will not kill internal process, why they have different pid?

Tags: linux, bash

For convenience, I put my server command into a function, but I background the function got a pid is not my server's pid.

```
myserver(){
# May contain complicate parameter
sleep 10
}
myserver > my.log &
pid=$!
ps aux|grep sleep
echo "Found PID " $pid is different from ps
```

So, if I `kill $pid` will not kill real server process(here is sleep).What should I do ?

**UPDATE**

```
sleep 10 &
pid=$!
ps aux|grep sleep
echo Found PID  $pid is same
```

**UPDATE**

In this case

```
myserver(){
# May contain complicate parameter
sleep 10
}
myserver > my.log &
kill $!
```

Will kill the sleep process, but actually, my server is `java -jar`, when I do `kill $!`, the java process will not get killed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to kill via the kill command you should provide the PID and not the Job Id.

Check [this post about JID and PID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172611/what-is-jid-job-id-and-is-it-always-smaller-than-pid)

**Update on Comment:**

Are u sre you are providing it right?

In my system:

```
$ sleep 20 &
[2] 10080
$ kill -9 $!
[2]-  Killed                  sleep 20
$
```

**Folow up**

Ok now I get it. Sorry i misinterpretted your question. What you describe is the expected behavior:

> $! Expands to the decimal process ID of the most recent background command (see Lists) executed from the current shell. (For example, background commands executed from subshells do not affect the value of "$!" in the current shell environment.) For a pipeline, the process ID is that of the last command in the pipeline.

So in that case maybe try  [this proposed solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56689/get-pid-of-a-function-executed-in-the-background)

**Update on Question:**

Ok, in the case of java proces I would try a regexp:

```
pkill -f 'java.*<your process name or some -classpath jar or something unique to the process you want to kill>'
```

In fact, any string or classpath jar that came along with this command and would result to a match would do the job.

Comment: [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) said, the `$!` is last command PID.

Comment: But if you put the command to the function and background the function, the pid is not the internal process pid.

Comment: There is a little different, I updated my question.I can understand why they got different pid, because the function is run in a sub shell, the internal process is another process.